# Can key loggers exist in Ubuntu, and if so, how can they be detected and removed?

Tags: ubuntu, security, keylogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux keylogger without root or sudo! Is it real?](https://superuser.com/questions/301646/linux-keylogger-without-root-or-sudo-is-it-real)

Is it possible for a malicious website to install a key logger on my Ubuntu desktop?

If so, how can I detect and deactivate the key logger?

Comment: As long as you are not running as root user it should not be possible.

Comment: even on home folder/browser?

Comment: A key logger would have to hook into the kernel event device, or X messages. Regular users don't have permissions to do that.

Comment: @Keith: False, see `xinput`.

Comment: @cYrus That is for X windows, and X runs as root. It's basically acting as a proxy. The actual device node is usually protected from non-root access.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, though unlikely. It would be more likely to have a repository that is hacked to include a keylogger.

For more information, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/334417/82812)

Comment: One obvious way: hack the Ubuntu repositories and add a keylogger component to, say, the Xorg package.

Comment: The incredible lack of detail and ridiculous claims in this answer is amazing.  Almost as amazing as the fact that it was selected as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

There is a claim of a Linux keylogger that doesn't need root.

See this other question [Linux keylogger without root or sudo! Is it real?](https://superuser.com/questions/301646)